# Returning an array of arrays using Maps in Swift, can someone confirm my understanding of this piece of code?

Tags: swift, function, dictionary

My understanding of the following code is:

```
func generateRandomData() -> [[UIColor]] {
    let numberOfRows = 2
    let numberOfItemsPerRow = 7
    return (0..<numberOfRows).map { _ in
        return (0..<numberOfItemsPerRow).map { _ in UIColor.randomColor() }
    }
}
```

**Explanation**:

```
// Returns an array of arrays 
func generateRandomData() -> [[UIColor]] {

    // 2 - Defines local variables
    let numberOfRows = 2
    let numberOfItemsPerRow = 7

    // 3 - From 0 to numberOfRows creates a map? 
    // 4 - For each element applies the high order function map using the function defined on the right
    return (0..<numberOfRows).map { _ in
        // For each element in the array applies another high order map function that creates numberOfItemsPerRow colours
        return (0..<numberOfItemsPerRow).map { _ in UIColor.randomColor() }
    }
}
```

**What the code does**:

So basically the code uses two times the map keyword and creates a total of `#numberOfItemsPerRow` arrays each containing `#numberOfItemsPerRow` items that are each of type UIColor.

Is this correct?

Comment: `Is this correct?` Yes. // Just a note: Playgrounds are awesome! Paste your code in a Playground, add `print(generateRandomData())` and open the Playground's console to see the results. :)

Comment: Yes, except `map` is not a keyword. The word "keyword" has a specific meaning in programming language syntax.

Comment: Ok, I am going to try now .. thanks a lot

Comment: @molbdnilo would you simply call it function? The formal language swift will be breaking down the line of code and search for known "tokens", so I thought that these could be called "keywords". What's the canonic way to call these elements of code?

Comment: @mm24 What you call it depends on what you're talking about – the identifier itself, or the entity it names. In other words, if you're talking about the structure or the meaning of the program. So in this case you would probably say that you call, or apply, the function `map` twice (as opposed to 'wrote the word "map" twice'). Keywords are "special" words; examples in Swift are "if", "for" and "get". You can find a list of Swift's keywords in the section "Keywords and Punctuation" in the Swift Programming language book.

Answer (score 0):

So the code understanding was **correct**.

As someone suggested a good way to verify my understanding is to use [playgrounds](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=24).

Another **useful article** that helped me understanding a bit more the new features of Swift is the following:

https://www.weheartswift.com/higher-order-functions-map-filter-reduce-and-more/